# Fill previous months within quarter in r

Tags: r

I have following data frames such as

```
dummy_ts_1 <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("1990-03-31","1990-06-30","1990-09-30","1990-12-31","1991-03-31","1991-06-30","1991-09-30","1991-12-31","1992-03-31","1992-06-30")),
                   GDP=c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000))

dummy_ts_2 <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("1980-01-31","1980-04-30","1980-07-31","1980-10-31","1981-01-31","1981-04-30","1981-07-31","1981-10-31","1982-01-31","1982-04-30")),
                     GDP=c(150,160,250,247,300,400,500,600,700,1000))
```

and I need fill out previous months within the same quarter (data.table::quarter(dummy_ts_1)) equally so the desired output should look like

```
> dummy_ts_1
         Date  GDP
   1990-01-31  33.33333
   1990-02-31  33.33333         
   1990-03-31  33.33333
   1990-04-30  66.66667
   1990-05-30  66.66667
   1990-06-30  66.66667
   1990-07-30  100
   1990-08-30  100
   1990-09-30  100
   1990-10-31  133.3333
   1990-11-31  133.3333
   1990-12-31  133.3333
```

Is there any simple way, how to achieve desired output? Thank you for any of your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure there's a pretty way, but here's one solution:

```
require(lubridate)

#dummy DF with date and GDP
dummy_ts_1    <-    data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("1990-03-31","1990-06-30","1990-09-30","1990-12-31")), GDP=c(100,200,300,400))

dummy_ts_1$new_gdp <- dummy_ts_1$GDP / 3        #store monthly GDP values
dummy_ts_1$quarter <- quarter(dummy_ts_1$Date)  #store quarter 

#create month-end date sequence                 
start         <-    as.Date("1990-01-01")
end           <-    as.Date("1990-12-01")
months        <-    seq.Date(start, end, by = 'month')
new_months    <-    c()
for(i in 1:length(months))
{
  new_months[i] <- ceiling_date(months[i], "month") - days(1)
}

#store in new data frame
new_df          <-      data.frame(months = as.Date(new_months, origin = '1970-01-01'))
new_df$quarter  <-      quarter(new_df$months)

#merge with dummy_ts_1 to get final results
new_df          <-      merge(new_df, subset(dummy_ts_1, select = c('quarter', 'new_gdp')), by = 'quarter', all.x = TRUE)
```

which yields:

```
> new_df
   quarter     months   new_gdp
1        1 1990-01-31  33.33333
2        1 1990-02-28  33.33333
3        1 1990-03-31  33.33333
4        2 1990-04-30  66.66667
5        2 1990-05-31  66.66667
6        2 1990-06-30  66.66667
7        3 1990-07-31 100.00000
8        3 1990-08-31 100.00000
9        3 1990-09-30 100.00000
10       4 1990-10-31 133.33333
11       4 1990-11-30 133.33333
12       4 1990-12-31 133.33333
```

Comment: This is great solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The yearmon class directly represents years and months without day so that you don't have to force fit this into dates.  Convert the series to zoo class and the time index to yearmon at the same time giving zq.  Then get the range of values `rng` -- a pair giving the first and last time values.  From that we can create a sequence or grid of time values `g` and merge that back with zq to give zm.  `na.locf` can then be used to fill in the NA values giving `zm`.  We can just leave it as a zoo series so that we can use all the other facilities of zoo but if you want to turn it back into a data frame use `fortify.zoo`.

```
library(zoo)

zq <- read.zoo(dummy_ts_1, FUN = as.yearmon)
rng <- range(time(zq))
g <- as.yearmon(seq(rng[1] - 2/12, rng[2], by = 1/12))
zm <- na.locf(merge(zq, zoo(, g)), fromLast = TRUE) / 3

DF <- fortify.zoo(zm)  # optional
```

giving:

```
> DF
      Index        zm
1  Jan 1990  33.33333
2  Feb 1990  33.33333
3  Mar 1990  33.33333
4  Apr 1990  66.66667
5  May 1990  66.66667
6  Jun 1990  66.66667
7  Jul 1990 100.00000
8  Aug 1990 100.00000
9  Sep 1990 100.00000
10 Oct 1990 133.33333
11 Nov 1990 133.33333
12 Dec 1990 133.33333
13 Jan 1991 166.66667
14 Feb 1991 166.66667
15 Mar 1991 166.66667
16 Apr 1991 200.00000
17 May 1991 200.00000
18 Jun 1991 200.00000
19 Jul 1991 233.33333
20 Aug 1991 233.33333
21 Sep 1991 233.33333
22 Oct 1991 266.66667
23 Nov 1991 266.66667
24 Dec 1991 266.66667
25 Jan 1992 300.00000
26 Feb 1992 300.00000
27 Mar 1992 300.00000
28 Apr 1992 333.33333
29 May 1992 333.33333
30 Jun 1992 333.33333
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
dummy_ts_1$GDP <- dummy_ts_1$GDP / 3
dummy_ts_1.b <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("1990-02-01"), 
                                  length=30, by="1 month") - 1,
                         GDP=with(dummy_ts_1, 
                                  unlist(lapply(seq_along(GDP), 
                                                function(x) rep(GDP[x], 3)))))
```

### Yields:

```
> dummy_ts_1.b
Date       GDP
1  1990-01-31  33.33333
2  1990-02-28  33.33333
3  1990-03-31  33.33333
4  1990-04-30  66.66667
5  1990-05-31  66.66667
6  1990-06-30  66.66667
7  1990-07-31 100.00000
8  1990-08-31 100.00000
9  1990-09-30 100.00000
10 1990-10-31 133.33333
11 1990-11-30 133.33333
12 1990-12-31 133.33333
13 1991-01-31 166.66667
14 1991-02-28 166.66667
15 1991-03-31 166.66667
16 1991-04-30 200.00000
17 1991-05-31 200.00000
18 1991-06-30 200.00000
19 1991-07-31 233.33333
20 1991-08-31 233.33333
21 1991-09-30 233.33333
22 1991-10-31 266.66667
```